# Text on the left side of the symbol in matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

Is there any built-in function/method or concise way to bring the text on left side of marker/symbol in legend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this can be done by setting the parameter `markerfirst`of the `matplotlib.pyplot.legend` to `False`.

> [markerfist](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) : bool
>   If True, legend marker is placed to the left of the legend label. If False, legend marker is placed to the right of the legend label. Default is True.

Something like that:

```
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s, label='sine')
ax.legend(markerfirst=False)

plt.show()
```

I hope this is what you were looking for :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks